# Is xmlHttpRequest imlementation optimized enough to send thousands of requests without page reload?

Tags: javascript, ajax, optimization, xmlhttprequest

We need to develop a client application that has to update some values (about 10-20 integers) each second, over HTTP protocol (however, the HTTP server is running the same machine, so requesting 'localhost' is fast). 
Since the UI must be easily modified, the decision was made to develop simply a HTML website and update the values using xmlHttpRequest (actually, using jQuery).

The problem is that the client is supposed to work continuously a whole year with no restart... This gives 3600 requests per hour, 86 400 per day, finally **30 758 400** requests per year. I'm very afraid how the browser will deal with such amount of requests... Has anyone any experience with "stresstest" of AJAX requests? 
Would reloading the page once a day help the browser with cleaning up memory?

Comment: I don't think there would be an issue with the AJAX bit, but rather any browser left "open" on a PC without restarts for a full year might expose memory leaks etc. that would bring it to its knees sooner.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't batch those updates?

Comment: I have trouble believing that the UI is going to be used to decide on 10-20 updates every second. Surely it sets some setting, and then that information can be used by another process?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what data are you sending back to the server that **changes** every second?  If it doesn't change that frequently, can you send every 5 or 10 seconds... or better yet, send (or batch up) data when it changes.

Comment: whoops, I think I didn't described it precisely enough. It's the server-side data that might change unexpectedly, and I need the UI to display quite recent values. So the UI updates itself (refreshes) each second

Comment: ah, ok.  So this is "like" a stock ticker type thing where you are polling the server for updates to get the latest price.  If you have to hit the server like this every second... all I can suggest is to optimize everything possible. Use JSON, Gzip the content, only send back data when there is a change, and send an HTTP 204 response code http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5 when there is no updated data to return, and if you don't need cookies sent with this data, serve it up from a cookieless server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue: Javascript runtime performance varies from browser to browser. You'd be better off finding a fast, stable browser than worrying about jQuery's AJAX performance. I'd be much more worried about keeping an instance of a browser rendering and executing for a whole year.

Second issue: javascript in the browser isn't a timing-precise language. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are unreliable and do not guarantee timing. jQuery's author wrote [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/) on Javascript time issues, so Javascript might lead to some problems if you need that really precise timing.

Third issue: if your client needs to run for 365 days without restarting, then aren't the sacrifices you're making by choosing to build an HTML/JS frontend somewhat silly for the loft goal of "easily editable?"

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm considering Firefox or, better, Chromium. The precise timing is not important at all, I just need the UI to keep updating all the time. The reason behind choosing HTML frontend is also because we want it to be accessible via other devices (like a smartphone connected to a local WiFi).

Comment: Would suggest Chrome rather than Chromium as Chromium is the cutting edge/less tested build.

Comment: @migajek I think I might have misunderstood your requirement re: 1 year of client uptime.  Anyways, look for long-term support releases of browsers. Chromium is great for developers who want fast features now, but it is not a production build, and thus should not be used for production purposes. Maybe a [site-specific browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser) would be the best type of solution for your desktop machines?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they're not using IE and you'll be off to a flying start.

Answer (score 1):

xmlHttpRequest is able to handle that much queries (short-polling fw like comet does this), but ... lots of queries may have an impact on the browser's responding capabilities depending on the browser. You can easily scale down the number of queries by a 10-20 factor just by requesting all integers together (using json data structure for example). You may have a look at short-polling as well as it is designed for that kind of purpose.

Comment: it is already implemented as you described, all the values are requested and received together in JSON format, than each is assigned to it's DOM node. But it's still 1 request per second